# I am having difficulties writing a factorial program

Tags: java, factorial

the program should ask user for a positive integer and print a factorial table. And if the input is less than 0 the output or program should stop.

Give me a positive integer: 5

Output:

5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1

The factorial of 5 is 120

Give me a postive integer: -5

Output: invalid Input! Programmed Stop

P.s: i am a beginner.
I am using Netbean IDE

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. *(Not my downvote)*

Comment: Javascript or java?

Comment: Im sorry its java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Just loop through the numbers.

```js
var input = prompt("What number would you like me to give you the factorial of?");
if (input > 0) {
  var answer = 1;
  var string = input + " =";
  for (var i = input; i >= 1; i--) {
    answer *= i;
    string += " " + i
    if (i != 1) {
      string += " x"
    }
  }

  console.log(string)
  console.log("The factorial of " + input + " is " + answer)
} else {console.log("Invalid input! Program stopped.")}
```

Java (assumes the input is in the variable `input`):

```
if (input > 0) {
  int answer = 1;
  String stringAnswer = input + " =";
  for (int i = input; i >= 1; i--) {
    answer *= i;
    stringAnswer += " " + i
    if (i != 1) {
      stringAnswer += " x"
    }
  }

  System.out.println(stringAnswer)
  System.out.println("The factorial of " + input + " is " + answer)
} else {System.out.println("Invalid input! Program stopped.")}
```

Comment: I need java not Javascript, im sorry.

Comment: Oh okay, will make it java

Comment: @JennieKim look now. it assumes the input is in the variable `input` so you can use the scanner there (if you know how to collect user input. if you don't i can add that  too)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the number is less than 0 otherwise calculate the factorial

```js
let x = prompt('Please enter a positive integer');

if (x < 0) {
  console.log('invalid Input! Programmed Stop')
} else {
  let val = 1;
  for (let k = 1; k <= x; k++) {
    val *= k
  }
  console.log(val)
}
```

Comment: read what the expected output of the program is

Comment: @SheshankS. what is wrong in my understanding?.It is only the output statement?

Comment: i think he also wants 5! = 5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1

Comment: See my answer he wanted that specific output

Comment: Sorry its not javascript, its for java.